# Makefile error while creating Docker image

Tags: linux, docker, makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to create Docker image using Makefile and following in the content on my Makefile

```
NAME   := bluehubs/bluehubs
TAG    := $(shell git log -1 --pretty=%H)
IMG    := ${NAME}:${TAG}
LATEST := ${NAME}:latest

build:
    $(info $$IMG is [${IMG}])
    $(info $$LATEST is [${LATEST}])
    docker build -t ${IMG} .
```

it throws an error as shown below:

```
$IMG is [bluehubs/bluehubs:9e8c3566e19cc86fb74b246dee86421a3f6d32bc]
$LATEST is [bluehubs/bluehubs:latest]
make: *** No rule to make target '9e8c3566e19cc86fb74b246dee86421a3f6d32bc', needed by 'build'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the commands for your make target `build:` are not indented with <kbd>Tab</kbd> but with spaces. This is a common error with Makefiles, but in this special case the error message is a bit strange.

The lines

```
$(info ...)
```

seem to work when indented with spaces, but the line

```
docker build -t ${IMG} .
```

which is not properly indented is expanded to

```
docker build -t bluehubs/bluehubs:9e8c3566e19cc86fb74b246dee86421a3f6d32bc .
```

which results in a rule that defines the targets `docker`, `build`, `-t` and `bluehubs/bluehubs` to depend on `9e8c3566e19cc86fb74b246dee86421a3f6d32bc` and `.`

As `build` is your default target, `make` checks for its dependency `9e8c3566e19cc86fb74b246dee86421a3f6d32bc` which is not found.

To fix the problem you must make sure that **every line in the recipe, i.e. the commands to execute, must start with a <kbd>Tab</kbd> character**.

It doesn't matter if you have spaces **after** a <kbd>Tab</kbd>, but you should use an editor that has a special mode for Makefiles or that at least shows if the line is indented with spaces or with a <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

To avoid errors in Makefiles I recommend not to use spaces for indentation at all.

Comment: Thank you @Bodo for explaining the error, I tried to intend it with manual 4 spaces as well but still, it throws the same error. Any suggestion on how I can get it to work?

Comment: I think you misread the answer.  In a makefile recipe lines (commands that are run) must be indented with a TAB character.  Not 4 spaces, not 8 spaces, but a single TAB character.  You should verify that your text editor is not replacing your TAB character with 8 spaces but is actually putting a TAB into your file.

Comment: Quoting the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recipe-Syntax): "Each line in the recipe **must start with a tab**...". I would suggest using an editor that has a makefile mode, which will flag incorrect indented recipe lines.